# How to update a list that contains values as dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Hi frens I have the following form of data

```
fields = [{'name':'xxx', 'age':24, 'location':'city_name'},
          {'name':'yyy', 'age':24, 'location':'city_name'}]
```

Now I want to update the location in two dicts and the save the fields in the same format.How to do it?I am beginner.

Comment: `fields[0]['location'] = 'here'; fields[1]['location'] = 'there'`

Comment: Hi @falsetru thanks for ur answer how to write it in a for loop?

Comment: I posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set same location for both fields.

```
>>> fields = [{'name':'xxx', 'age':24, 'location':'city_name'},
...           {'name':'yyy', 'age':24, 'location':'city_name'}]
>>> for field in fields:
...     field['location'] = 'loc'
...
>>> fields
[{'age': 24, 'name': 'xxx', 'location': 'loc'}, {'age': 24, 'name': 'yyy', 'location': 'loc'}]
```

To set different locations, use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> for field, loc in zip(fields, ['here', 'there']):
...     field['location'] = loc
...
>>> fields
[{'age': 24, 'name': 'xxx', 'location': 'here'}, {'age': 24, 'name': 'yyy', 'location': 'there'}]
```